# Nominalization of verbs in japanese

Tags: grammar, verbs, nominalization

What is the purpose of verb nominalization in Japanese? How do I know when to nominalize a verb and when not to? Still, knowing there are different ways of nominalizing i.e using the i form of the verb, adding no or koto, how do i know which pattern to use? Can you please give answers with examples to illustrate?thank you

Comment: There are times when you want to express your idea using a verb where syntax expects only a noun as is the case with prepositional phrases in English. How does your language deal with such a case?